# django HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, urllib

I want when i load the page, the def celphone works and get the content of the span tag from the url and print it on the page but it returns error.

views.py:

```
from django.http import *
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
import pymysql



def cellphone(request):
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from urllib.request import urlopen

    url ='http://www.digikala.com/Product/DKP-95906/Huawei-Mate-S-Dual-SIM-64GB-Mobile-Phone/%DA%AF%D9%88%D8%B4%D9%8A-%D9%85%D9%88%D8$'
    data = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    price =  soup.body.find('span', attrs={'id':'frmLblPayablePriceAmount'}).text
    return render(request, 'system.html', {'price': price})
```

This raised this error:

```
Exception Type:     HTTPError
Exception Value:    HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

What does it mean by bad request?

Comment: Try escaping your url string correctly...

Comment: Yes it helped thank you.